# How to scale cholesky factorization on multiple GPUs

Tags: parallel-processing, gpu, distributed-computing, gpgpu

I have implemented Cholesky Factorization for solving large linear equation on GPU using ATI Stream SDK. Now I want to exploit computation power of more and more GPUs and I want to run this code on multiple GPUs.

Currently I have One Machine and One GPU installed on it and cholesky factorization is running properly.
I want to do it for N machine and all have one GPU installed on them. So Suggest me how should I proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to be aware that this approach will introduce three levels of latency for any communication between nodes:

1. GPU memory on machine 1 to main memory on machine 1
2. Main memory on machine 1 to main memory on machine 2
3. Main memory on machine 2 to GPU memory on machine 2

A good first step will be to do some back of the envelop calculations to determine if the speed up you gain by splitting the problem between multiple machines will outweigh the latency you introduce.

Once you're sure the approach is the one you want to follow, then it's pretty much up to you to implement this correctly.  Note that, currently, NVIDIA's CUDA or OpenCL libraries will be better choices for you because they allow you to access the GPU for computation without having it coupled with an X session.  Once ATI's OpenCL implementation supports the GPU, then this should also be a viable option.

Since you already have a working GPU implementation, here are the basic steps you must follow:

- Determine how you update your factorization algorithm to support processing by separate nodes
- Set up the data exchange between N computers (I notice you have opted for MPI for this)
- Set up the scatter operation that will divide the input problem amongst the computational nodes
- Set up the data exchange between a machine and its GPU
- Set up the gather operation that will gather the results from the nodes into the one node

Answer (score 0):

It's a very specialised question. Suggest you check the [Stream developer resources](http://developer.amd.com/samples/gpusamples/Pages/default.aspx) and the [Stream Developer Forums](http://forums.amd.com/devforum/).

Answer (score 0):

I showed this Q to a colleague of mine who knows about these things.
He suggested you use ScaLAPACK.